# How to restore Lenovo ThinkVantage Rescue And Recovery Partition?

Tags: thinkpad, recovery-partition

I've created a backup of the Rescue And Recovery Partition using clonezilla.
Now, on a new disk, I've recovered the partition using clonezilla, however when I try to boot it I get:

```
Missing operating system
```

message.

How can I make it bootable again?

I've set the bootable flag on the partition using fdisk [the one from clonezilla].

Any tips?

Comment: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T61-and-prior-T-series-ThinkPad/Can-t-boot-Rescue-and-Recovery-on-new-hard-disk-in-T42p/td-p/386517 seems to be addressing this questions

Comment: Thanks FredrikD. Unfortunately when I run Super Grub 2 CD it won't boot the RnR partition :/

Comment: @Krystian I would be looking for a recovery disc set for your model, by the way what model is it?

Comment: it's T410, I can;t find anything online. I think I'll just install windows from some random iso and try to install the rescue and recovery tools.

Comment: I was able to install windows 7 and Lenovo Rescue and Recovery. I am able to boot the RnR using thinkvantage button, but when I try to do a full system restore I get a message saying that product recovery function has been removed from  this system...